# Do I need to lock the DB table or just synchronize the method that writes to the DB when called from different threads?

Tags: java, database, synchronization, locking, eclipselink

I am developing a web-service that will be used by several clients. I am using EclipseLink as JPA provider. When calling a method in the web-service from a client, then I have observed that EclipseLink uses a thread in a thread pool to call the method which means the method can be called simultaneously at the same time from different threads in that thread pool.

In some of the methods I do some critical writes to some tables in the database and I need do implement some kind of locking mechanism. Is it a good practice to synchronize the methods when writing to database or do I need to lock the entire table in MySQL?

Some of the writes looks like this in pseudo code:

```
   1. insert_into_TableA(getLastInsertedIdInTableA + 1);
   2. insert_into_TableB(getLastInsertedIdInTableB + 1);
   3. int id_A = getLastInsertedIdInTableA + 1;
   4. int id_B = getLastInsertedIdInTableB + 1;
   5. insert_into_TableAB(id_A, id_B);
```

Database structure below:

```
TableA          TableAB         TableB
pk tableA_id    pk tableA_id    pk tableB_id
                pk tableB_id
```

My second question: I am not using `autoincrement` in my tables, so is it a good practice, when inserting new rows, to get the ID of the last inserted row and then just increment it by 1 to insert the new row? Or can I use some good methods in EclipseLink to do this for me?

Comment: Why do you think you need to lock the tables? MySQL should handle the concurrency. After all that's what a database is for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, MySQL is handling the concurrency but not in cases where the logiscs are on the application level, like in my case. Two different transaction, like Aaron Digulla stated below, can get the same getLastInsertedIdInTableA value and the concurrency handler will fail by inserting new rows with the same `getLastInsertedIdInTableA` value as `tableA_id`.

Comment: Then you should use a different strategy to "calculate" that last inserted value. If you were on a different DBMS I'd suggest using sequences, but with MySQL you don't have that option. So you are right you'll have to sacrifice performance for correctness.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: do you know if it is a good practice to lock the methods in this way if the columns are not auto_incremented?

Comment: Good practice in terms of performance? No. Good practice in terms of correctness? Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a "[transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)."

Usually, the container will make sure that a new transaction is started when a new request comes in and commits the transaction after the code to process the request completes (unless an exception is thrown).

The problem is `getLastInsertedId` - this won't work. Different transactions might see the same value here. The solution is to let the database figure out a new, free ID for you.

Use an "identity column" instead. In MySQL, that would be [NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: How can I get the `getLastInsertedId` problem to work? Is it by making the column auto_increment?

Comment: Yes. Directly after the `insert`, you can run the query `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which will give you the last inserted ID for the current transaction. Since each thread gets its own transaction, this will work.

Comment: Uhm, ok. But if the design solution is to not use auto_increment columns, is the only way to lock the methods (synchronize, ReentrantLock etc) that is writing to the database? Or is there any design pattern for this kind of case?

Comment: If the design asks not to use auto_increment columns, it is broken beyond repair. Any workaround will cause subtle problems. The only correct solution that always works is using auto increment - this is specifically why this feature was invented in the first place!